# Rolles theorem: differentiabilty open brackets significance

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

1. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863979/922054    Related to Rolle's theorem : Here it is said that $f(x)$ is non-differentiable at endpoints of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, but isn't it okay to talk of endpoint differentiability as only left handed one or right handed one only in case of end points?
   And then we can say a function differentiable in $[a,b]$ ?
2. Are there any exceptions where it might fails to work ( that is Rolle's theorem ) if we include endpoints in differentiability leaving the above example?
3. And do we say that here the $(-1,0)$ point is non-differentiable ?[image]

Comment: Looking at the picture, what do you think the slope of the tangent line should be at the end point?

Comment: The picture i made was combining two graphs of functions , but yeah i agree at that point its infinity since slope is infinity

Comment: @user1046533 is it correct to say we can check the graph of f'(x) and observe if there is a discontinuity at any point then we can say that f(x) is non differentuable at that point ? As such for this case the smoth curve didnt lead me believe its non differentiablr but by observing the f'(x) graph we may say right?

Comment: The function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ defined on $[-1,1]$ is continuous but not differentiable at the end points even you consider side-differentiability. The follows from the limit definition.

Comment: I see okay understood @user1046533